# Segmentation fault when calling a function from the main function (generated NASM code)

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, nasm

I'm developing a compiler which targets x86 and amd64. My compiler works currently pretty well on 64-bit computers. On 32-bit I am getting a segfault.

A simple empty program (only main method) compiles to the following assembly:

```
extern GC_init
global main
global f_main
segment .data
segment .text
main:
    ; argc = dword [ebp+8]
    ; argv = dword [ebp+12]
    push    edx
    ; line 3

    ; proceed GC_init[]
    xor     dword eax, dword eax
    call    GC_init
    ; line 4

    ; proceed function@main[argc, argv]
    push    dword [ebp+12]
    push    dword [ebp+8]
    xor     dword eax, dword eax
    call    f_main
    sub     dword esp, dword 8

    pop     edx
    ret
f_main:
    push    edx
    ; line 7

    ; oax = 0
    mov     dword eax, dword 0
    ; line 8

    .L0:

    pop     edx
    ret
```

`f_main` is the actual main method. `main` just calls `GC_init` and then `f_main`.

I'm compiling and running the code using the following commands:

```
$ nasm -f elf -o test.o test.asm 
$ gcc -o etest test.o -lgc
$ ./etest
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I debugged the program using GDB and found that the segmentation fault comes from the second push-instruction (`push dword [ebp+12]`).

Here is some information about my computer:

```
$ uname -a
Linux [name] 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:30:01 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never even set up `ebp`, so that's why you get a fault. The standard function prologue consists of `push ebp; mov ebp, esp`. You don't have to follow that pattern, but if you don't initialize `ebp` then you should access the arguments and the locals relative to `esp` (and mind the fact that `push` changes it).

Also, to restore the stack pointer you need to add to it, not subtract. That is replace `sub dword esp, dword 8` with `add dword esp, dword 8`.

A possible implementation of `main` could look like:

```
sub esp, 12        ; allocate space for edx and 2 outgoing arguments
mov [esp + 8], edx ; save edx
xor eax, eax       ; I assume you have a special reason for this
call GC_init
mov eax, [esp + 16]
mov [esp], eax     ; copy 1st argument
mov eax, [esp + 20]
mov [esp + 4], eax ; copy 2nd argument
xor eax, eax
call f_main
mov edx, [esp + 8] ; restore edx
add esp, 12        ; restore stack
ret
```